# crystal report, subreport details section not displaying the next batch of records

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I put a subreport in the footer of my main report and I set its details section to display five records per page (through the paging tab). 
I am sure my query returns nine records.

Upon previewing the report, on the first page, it displays the first five records. 
However, on the second page, it also displays the first five records not the remaining four records.

I am not sure where is the problem since I just started using crystal reports. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your sub report links.

This will link the data from your main report to your sub report.  In Crystal 2008 you right click on the sub report and choose 'Change Sub report links...' option.  Then you can select the data to flow from the main report to your sub report.  Otherwise your sub report is being viewed as a completely separate report that you are just inserting on top of your main report and it will be the same at every instance.

Also, it might be a good idea to use groups instead of the details section when inserting sub reports.

Comment: but my subreport has a different query compared to my main report. it is my intention to put different query result in my subreport

Comment: Given your configuration, each time you have a footer it will call for a brand new sub report. It will re query for your sub report in every footer.  That is why I recommended you use groups link your data so you wont get the same data from the same new query each time you have a footer.